# Android Volley NoConnectionError

Tags: java, android, android-volley, general-network-error

I use the same type of request in my app for over 10 different connection types, all of them work except this one and I can not find out why, the only difference between them is the params being sent. If I manually send the request (by typing the data into URL bar) everything comes back fine, but when volley tries to connect it says `NoConnectionError` is happening. I have tried this with my 4G connection and WIFI connection and it always returns the same.

**UPDATE**

Okay so I took out the params on sending the lat/long and now the server sends a response back. Am I sending the lat/long wrong?

```
public void updateLoc(final double latitude, final double longitude, final Context context)
{
    if (context != null)
    {
        RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(context);
        StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, URL_FOR_ACCOUNT,
                new Response.Listener<String>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(String response)
                    {
                        Log.e("Network", "Response " + response);
                    }
                }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                if (error instanceof TimeoutError) {
                    Log.e(TAG,"Update Location Request timed out.");
                }else if (error instanceof NoConnectionError){
                    Log.e(TAG,"Update Location no connection.");
                } else if (error instanceof AuthFailureError) {
                    Log.e(TAG,"Auth failure");
                } else if (error instanceof ServerError) {
                    Log.e(TAG,"Server Error");
                } else if (error instanceof NetworkError) {
                  Log.e(TAG,"Network Error");
                } else if (error instanceof ParseError) {
                    Log.e(TAG,"Parse Error");
                }
            }
        }) {
            //adding parameters to the request
            @Override
            protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
                Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<>();
                params.put("command", "updateLoc");
                params.put("appVersion", version);
                params.put("androidVersionNumber", Integer.toString(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT));
                params.put("email", userEmail);
                params.put("lat", String.valueOf(latitude));
                params.put("long", String.valueOf(longitude));
                return params;
            }
        };
```

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I figured out what my error was, you can not post things such as `long`, `string`, `boolean` ect it appears, even if they are being cast as a String name. I changed this line:

```
 params.put("long", String.valueOf(longitude));
```

to this line:

```
 params.put("lng", String.valueOf(longitude));
```

and everything is back to working fine. I couldn't find any documentation that says you can't use those as String names.